# Relational model of database management system

Tags: database

Instead of having separate relation what if the problem of having one big relation that will store all the data related to a system?

Comment: Welcome to SO. It is unclear of what you are asking. Please support us with further informations and edit your post.

Answer (score 0):

A single database may not fulfill all the needs of a complete system. For example : Lets take a ecommerce website. Here you have following important things :

```
Customer Information
Order information
Inventory Information etc.
```

Now if you see these three are not related to each other other than that they are all a part of ecommerce system. You don't need to store the user information along with inventory information in a single table as they are not related.

After this part is answered, Now, you can have doubts  so as to why we need normalization. The objectives of normalization as mentioned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) are:

> 1. To free the collection of relations from undesirable insertion, update and deletion dependencies;
> 2. To reduce the need for restructuring the collection of relations, as new types of data are introduced, and thus increase the life span of application programs;
> 3. To make the relational model more informative to users;
> 4. To make the collection of relations neutral to the query statistics, where these statistics are liable to change as time goes by.